# Using normal load function for a matfile containing an object

Tags: matlab, object

I defined a class and created the object Obj. Now I want to save Obj along with other variables to a certain folder:

```
filename = 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\file.mat' ;
save(filename,'Obj','var1','var2')
```

The normal and intuitive thing to do next is loading file.mat for further work:

```
load (file.mat)
```

Unfortunately Obj loses its structur and is not constructed as an object of my class but as matrix of uint32. There is a thread to this problem at mathworks.com:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/261903 but it is not helping me. All functions and classdef files and matfiles etc are in the same path.

thx for helping.

Comment: Is the folder in matlabs working directory?

Comment: Yes it is. Sometimes Matlab is very strange. I tried it again an it worked, I tried it another time and it did not. Maybe it has something to do with the exsting class instances. Something like using clear befor editing the object ...

Comment: Ok, if the class is complicated, then try to use the save format ´-v7.3´ that may be more stable. Also avoid using variable names and filenames like `file` and `Obj`, which may be reserved (I am not sure but it is safer to not risk anything). Also `save('myFile.mat','objName')` is enough to save the file.

Comment: Alright. If it occurs more often I will create a service request on mathworks.com and post the results here. Cheerio!